# Trouble with implementing abstract super class Java

Tags: java

I'm working on an assignment where I'm trying to implement a class that extends an abstract super class, but by using

```
    public class B extends A{}
```

However, that gives me the error that type B must implement the abstract method A.act, is there another way in which I can do this without using extends?

Using:

```
    public abstract class B extends A{}
```

Gives me a different error on another part of the assignment that should be correct.

What should I do? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

In order for `B` to instantiated by the JVM, it must not be `abstract`.  A abstract class is an idea or suggest of how a class might work, with some (or all) of the functionality needing to implemented by those classes that extended it.

For `B` to be instantiated, it must implement all the abstract methods of `A`.

To solve your problem, you must provide an implementation of the methods that `A` has marked as `abstract`...

```
public abstract class A {
     public abstract void implementMe();
}

public class B extends A {
    public void implementMe() {
        // Your implementation
    }
}
```

The reason for much of this is it allows you to pass `B` to methods and classes that use `A` and also change the way in which `A` works.  This is part of polymorphism, where one instance of object can act as its parent (`B` acting like it's `A`)

I don't know if it will help, but you could have a read of [Abstract classes
and methods](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ309_007.htm)

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried using the public abstract class A before using extends, but it gives me an error stating that type A is already defined. The initial error of type B must implement the inherited abstract method A also remains.

Answer (score 0):

don't declare method act in abstract class A as abstract method if you do not want to provide implemenation of act in B. But that may not be a right choice depending upon what you are trying to achieve.  In second case, when abstract class extends another abstract class,  use "implement" instead of "extends". hope it helps